# zip more than 2 variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to zip 3 variables as I loop on 3 different arrays but the data types are distorted, even though I can print the variables and they are the same, just that they end up being arrays or other data types... (If I print l1 instead of l1.class, I get the right output)

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = ['a','b','c']
```

then

```
a.zip(b).each do |l1,l2|
  puts l1.class, l2.class
end
```

gives:

```
Integer
Integer
Integer
Integer
Integer
Integer
```

Great! **BUT**

```
a.zip(b).zip(c).each do |l1,l2,l3|
  puts l1.class, l2.class, l3.class
end
```

gives

```
Array
String
NilClass
Array
String
NilClass
Array
String
NilClass
```

How do I zip the 3 variables, keeping their types?

Thank you!

Comment: [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) Docs show it takes any number of argument `Array`s. So I am not sure I understand.

Comment: Thank you  @engineersmnky, I was using the wrong syntax. If you think this might be useful for others, please write the answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland YES, thank you. I should read the docs next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e = a.zip(b)
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
e.zip(c)
  #=> [[[1, 1], "a"], [[2, 2], "b"], [[3, 3], "c"]]
```

shows the problem. See [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip).

Here are three ways you can obtain the desired result. All print

```
Integer
Integer
String
Integer
Integer
String
Integer
Integer
String
```

```
a.zip(b,c).each { |arr| puts *arr.map(&:class) }
```

Note

```
a.zip(b,c)
  #=> [[1, 1, "a"], [2, 2, "b"], [3, 3, "c"]]
```

If the *splat* operator (`*`) were removed the following would be printed:

```
[Integer, Integer, String]
[Integer, Integer, String]
[Integer, Integer, String]
```

---

```
a.each_index { |i| puts a[i].class, b[i].class, c[i].class }
  #=> [1,2,3]
```

---

```
[a.map(&:class), b.map(&:class), c.map(&:class)]
  .transpose
  .each { |r| puts *r }
  #=> [[Integer, Integer, String],
  #    [Integer, Integer, String], 
  #    [Integer, Integer, String]]
```

Comment: *"If the splat operator (`*`) were removed the following would be printed"* Would it though? :)

Comment: @engineersmnky, my bad. Thanks.

Comment: my point was splat or no splat the result is the same. You can even call puts outside the block  `puts a.zip(b,c).map {|arr| arr.map(&:class)}`. Every result will be identical, each class on a new line, due to the way `puts` handles Arrays.